# Ruby on Rails, When I look at console.log undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, console.log

```
$(function(){
  var $activeSlide = $('#slides .slide:first-child');
  //show first slides;
  // $activeSlide.addClass('showing');

  $('#decline').on('click', function(){
    console.log('decline')
    goToSlide('decline');
  });

  $('#approve').on('click', function(){
    var user_id = $activeSlide.data('id');

    console.log(user_id);
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "/approve/" + user_id,
      method: 'post', 
      dataType: "ajax"
    })
    goToSlide('approve');
  });

   function goToSlide(action){
     $activeSlide.removeClass('showing');
     $activeSlide = $activeSlide.next('.slide');

    if(action == 'approve'){
      console.log(action);
    } else {
      console.log(action);

    }

    $activeSlide.addClass('showing');
    //  slides[currentSlide] = 'slide';
      //currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
      //slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
    }


    });
```

using this tinder clone tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibRVysxvOdU&t=116s

[Log] undefined (application-72a9ee64d4b552e48811.js, line 140)
[Log] approve (application-72a9ee64d4b552e48811.js, line 152)

Comment: I don't know for sure which log message is printing, because I don't see the line numbers of the code. Also, I'd advise learning how to use `debugger` instead of relying purely on `console.log`.

Comment: However, my guess is that `$activeSlide.data('id')` is undefined? So, what is `$activeSlide`?  I see how you're fetching it in javascript, but you haven't shown how it's defined in HTML.